# node.js using two sockets with different ports

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am new to node.js and I am trying to open two ports using one ip address with 25000 receiving and sending and 25001 receiving. At the moment I can receive ok 
 on 25001 but when I try to send on 25000 nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

If it can't be done, I would be grateful for any advice on how to do this specifically using a web browser to start the code.

Kind Regards,
Jason.

```
var rcv = require('net');
var snd = require('net');

var receive = new rcv.Socket();
var send = new snd.Socket();

var loginok = 0;

receive.connect(25001, 'ipaddress', function() {
    console.log('Receive Connected');
});

receive.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('Received: ' + data);

    var sendresult = data.toString().split(",");

    if(sendresult[3] == 'Login Required')
    {
        send.connect(25000, 'ipaddress', function() {
            console.log('Send Connected');
        });

        send.write(...something);

        send.on('data', function(data1) {
            console.log(data1);
        });

        receive.destroy();
        send.destroy();
    }

});

receive.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Receive Connection closed');
});

send.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Send Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: I assume `send.connect()` is asynchronous, which means when you call `send.write`, the connection isn't established yet. You need to move the command inside the callback, below `console.log('Send Connected');`

Comment: You also can do this: `var Socket = require('net').Socket; var receive = new Socket(); var send = new Socket();`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this but still no joy. It is not connecting to port 25000. This is my output. Receive Connected
Received: 100,0,45,Login Required,

Receive Connection closed
Send Connection closed

Comment: You have to wait for your `send.connect()` to finish before you can send data on that socket.  You will also help yourself solve issues if you log all errors on both sockets.

Comment: So what is listening on port 25000?